# DNS issue in Google's cloud dns

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, bind, dig

I have a linux instance running in compute engine with a static IP open to the public. I purchased a domain name that matches the hostname of my instance (from google domains). It's been over 72 hours and the name still wont resolve. I assume I have misconfigured or overlooked something...I just cant tell what. here is some dig output that demonstrates I can resolve it using one the google domains ns, but not 8.8.8.8

```
rexfitzhugh ~ $ dig @ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com A fake.fqdn.com

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com A fake.fqdn.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 5864
;; flags: qr aa rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;fake.fqdn.com.     IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
fake.fqdn.com.  300 IN  A   MY.IP.HE.RE

;; Query time: 19 msec
;; SERVER: 216.239.32.109#53(216.239.32.109)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 29 17:19:31 CDT 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 65

rexfitzhugh ~ $ dig @8.8.8.8 A fake.fqdn.com 

; <<>> DiG 9.10.6 <<>> @8.8.8.8 A fake.fqdn.com
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 46050
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 512
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;fake.fqdn.com.     IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
yourenotadog.com.   299 IN  SOA ns-cloud-b1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 3 21600 3600 259200 300

;; Query time: 43 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Thu Apr 29 17:19:45 CDT 2021
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 139
```

Not sure what I'm missing here, but thanks for your help

Comment: Your question has no details on how you configured the DNS resource records. Start with who are the authoritative name servers registered at your domain registrar. Then show the DNS resource records that you created at that server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the fqdn to IP address mapping in a public hosted zone( say `google` `clouddns`) and make your registerer aware about the name-server(s) of that public hosted zone .

Also, if you can add some more details about where did you add your record and when you are resolving it using the name server `ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com`  is that on the machine in same project or different one .

Comment: This should be a comment to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Here is a screenshot i took of my configuration for cloud DNS (the domain provider is google domains)

https://pasteboard.co/JZLc2ht.png